# Confluence wiki XML RPC API system.list method

Tags: xml-rpc, wiki, confluence

Does the Confluence wiki XML RPC API provide a system or system.list method or some other method to programmatically list what methods are available via the XMLRPC interface?

Example:

```
auggy@stinkycheese ~ > xml-rpc-api2txt https://wiki.company.com/rpc/xmlrpc
An error occurred while trying to talk to the XML-RPC server:

Fault returned from XML RPC Server, fault code 0: java.lang.Exception: RPC handler object "system" not found and no default handler registered
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no reflection in the Confluence XML-RPC API that would allow it to inspect itself and report its available methods, sadly.

However, the XML-RPC API is near-identical to the SOAP API, and you can inspect/query the SOAP WSDL to see the methods that it supports - eg: https://confluence.atlassian.com/rpc/soap-axis/confluenceservice-v2?wsdl

There's also a reasonably accurate and up-to-date API listing on the public docs: https://developer.atlassian.com/display/CONFDEV/Confluence+XML-RPC+and+SOAP+APIs